# Optimize OpenVPN connection?

Tags: networking, network-protocols, openvpn

This is a big headache for me for a few days now.

I having 2 servers on different location. We use OpenVPN to connect between the 2 servers.

```
Server1 has a Uplink of ~100mbps (OPENVPN Server)
Server2 has a Uplink of ~50mbps  (OPENVPN Client)
```

However, after i config the openVPN within the 2, i can hardly surpass 2mbps speed.

I use HTTP to test the uplink of each other.

```
              HTTP, NO VPN         HTTP, WITH VPN
SV1<->SV2     48mbps(6MB/s)        2-3mbps (~200-300KB/s)
```

Here is my Configuration on serverside (SV1):

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
#tun-mtu 9000
fragment 0
mssfix 0
ca ca.crt
cert mysite.crt
key mysite.key
dh dh1024.pem
cipher none
auth none
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
max-clients 1
persist-key
persist-tun
#status openvpn-status.log
#verb 3
```

On Client Side (SV2)

```
client
proto udp
dev tun
#tun-mtu 9000
remote 123.34.56.7 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
#persist-key
#persist-tun
cipher none
auth none
ca ca.crt
cert mysite.crt
key mysite.key
comp-lzo
#verb 3
```

Most of the test on iperf showing the same speed at 1mbps.

```
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[1884]  0.0-10.0 sec  1.20 MBytes  1.00 Mbits/sec  6.220 ms   38/  893 (4.3%)
[1884] local 10.8.0.1 port 11100 connected with 10.8.0.6 port 54784
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[1884]  0.0-10.0 sec  1.21 MBytes  1.01 Mbits/sec  6.307 ms   29/  893 (3.2%)
[1884] local 10.8.0.1 port 11100 connected with 10.8.0.6 port 50475
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[1884]  0.0-10.0 sec  1.19 MBytes   996 Kbits/sec  6.564 ms   45/  893 (5%)
[1884] local 10.8.0.1 port 11100 connected with 10.8.0.6 port 44565
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter   Lost/Total Datagrams
[1884]  0.0-10.0 sec  1.20 MBytes  1.01 Mbits/sec  6.152 ms   34/  893 (3.8%)
```

What should I do to improve this?

Answer (score 2):

One reason might be that UDP traffic is shaped somewhere. Try running iperf with -u -p 1194 directly between the servers without using OpenVPN. If that is still slow try different ports and vary between UDP and TCP with iperf to see if it makes a difference.

If the CPU is really old in any of the servers also try removing the compression option comp-lzo.

Comment: Is it normal that if i set `-t=60` it is goes up to 6mbps and if i set `-t=180` it is go up to 16mbps?

Comment: When using TCP it takes time to reach the full possible speed of the connection so that might be ok. If this is with UDP I am puzzled.